# How to create one spreadsheet for each row that also imports that whole row in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm a teacher looking to create individual spreadsheets for students based on an assessment. The students will be listed in column A, and I want each of them to receive the information from column A to column G. In addition, they should also receive the headlines for each column (row 1 to 3).

Ideally, the script should also come with an email function (mail the document ID to the address found in column B or something like that).

Right now, I have found a script that creates a spreadsheet for each student, but I'm not quite sure how to also make the script grab the relevant information from the same sheet.

```
 function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('ADMIN');
    var item = menu.addItem('Create student copies', 'createStudents');
    item.addToUi();
  };

 function createStudents() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Fullclass');
    var range = sheet.getRange('A:A');
    var values = range.getValues();
    var df = DriveApp.getFolderById('1PgMa9Ow8xS      Zs6_kIuyw9mSHp');

 for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if( values[i][0] != '' ) {
    var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(values[i][0]);
    var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId());
    df.addFile(driveFile);
    DriveApp.removeFile(driveFile);
  }
 }
};
```

This would be such a massive timesaver for me if it was doable. Thanks to a ton to anyone who even reads this.

Comment: A spreadsheet for each `whatever` is never a good idea. Just do everything in a single spreadsheet and use `filter` or `query`

Comment: @I'-'I Regarding "never a good idea" I disagree as there a lot of use cases that could benefit from this.

Comment: Welcome Stylelimited. One of the rules of this sites is to give proper attribution. In this case that you mention that you found a script, it's expected that you include as minimum a link to the source of that script. For further details please checkout [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @Ruben May be so. But I strongly believe that the cons outweigh any possible pros. The main con being data management/organization is unnecessarily complicated. IMO, Consolidation is the way to go rather than segregation.

Comment: @I'-'I While this post doesn't include details about data size we could assume that this teacher has between 20 to 100 students (1 or several sessions/groups) also we rephrase the purpose of having separate spreadsheets to give each student their own assessment results which later will be shared with each of them and send a link by email.

Comment: @Ruben IMO, Better alternative is to just build a single webapp, which fetches and displays live data from a single sheet based on a email address login. You can also send a email to respective student's emails based on a single sheet.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use something like `sheet.getRange(row + ':' + row)` to get a whole row from a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object.

## Explanation

Let say that `row` is a row number. `row + ':' + row` returns a reference of the form `1:1` that makes reference to a whole row.

Once we have grab the row we could use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get its values or use any of the copyTo [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) methods to copy it to a new sheet.

Alternatively, instead of sending the whole row we could send only the corresponding cells from the row and from A to G columns by using `sheet.getRange('A' + row + ':G' + row)` or `sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 6)`.